# Python requests module results in SSL error for 301 redirects to a different domain

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the Python requests module (requests (2.7.0)) and tracking URL requests. 
Most of these URL's are supposed to trigger a 301 redirect however for some the domain changes as well. These URL's where the 301 is causing a domain name change i.e. x.y.com ends up as a.b.com I get a certificate verify failed. However I have checked and the cert on that site is valid and it is not a self signed cert.

For the others where the domain remains the same I do not get any errors so it does not seem to be linked to SSL directly else the others would fail as well.

Also what is interesting is that if I run the same script using curl instead of requests I do not get any errors.

I know I can suppress the request errors by setting verify=False but I am wondering why the failure occurs only when there is a domain name change.

Regards,
AB

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now. I believe the issue was linked to an old version of openssl. Once I upgraded even the 301 for a different domain goes through with no errors and that was with verify set to True.